# How to make a list of a mapping of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a long list of group_ids like so:

```
 @group_ids = @groups.map(&:group_id)
 Rails.logger.info @group_ids
 [182, 122, 181, 173, 167, 58, 13, 11, 180, 40, 71, 1, 29, 47, 142, 52, 174, 7, 168, 171, 156, 120, 79, 72, 54, 26, 65]
```

How can I take all those group_ids and output:

```
group_id:11 OR group_id:22 etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@group_ids =  [182, 122, 181, 173, 167, 58, 13, 11, 180, 40, 71, 1, 29, 47, 142, 52, 174, 7, 168, 171, 156, 120, 79, 72, 54, 26, 65]
@group_ids.map{|id| "group_id:#{id}"}.join(" OR ")
#=> "group_id:182 OR group_id:122 OR group_id:181 OR group_id:173 OR group_id:167 OR group_id:58 OR group_id:13 OR group_id:11 OR group_id:180 OR group_id:40 OR group_id:71 OR group_id:1 OR group_id:29 OR group_id:47 OR group_id:142 OR group_id:52 OR group_id:174 OR group_id:7 OR group_id:168 OR group_id:171 OR group_id:156 OR group_id:120 OR group_id:79 OR group_id:72 OR group_id:54 OR group_id:26 OR group_id:65"
```

Answer (score 6):

Just do:

```
@group_ids * " OR "
```

(Ruby is great)

Comment: Will it know not to add the OR to the last record?

Comment: It will, It is just the same as `@group_ids.join(" OR ")` (in this particular case)